# Number of total orderings

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders

Is there a name for the following type of ordering on some set $S$ {$a,b,c$} that includes only $>$ and $=$ for example:

$$a>b>c$$
$$a>b=c$$
$$a=b>c$$
$$a=b=c$$

Is there some name for these orderings?

---

I know that all these *satisfy* a *total preorder* on $S$, since a preoder on $S$ is simply one in which the elements are ordered by the  $\geq$ relation. But is there a name for these particular orderings?

Are my examples all instances of total orderings, since all members are comparable?

Is it okay to call these simply various "orderings" on $S$?

Comment: I don’t think it’s clear from your examples what you’re thinking. Is there an example of a total preorder you would NOT count?

Comment: A total preorder on $S$ simply orders all elements with $\geq$ but it does not specify whether $>$ or $=$. My examples are of some orderings that satisfy the total preorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a linear order of 3 points.
The 2nd and a 3rd are linear orders of 2 points.
The last is an order for a single point set.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider it a total ordering of a multiset. For example, for $a=b>c$, the set $\{a,b,c\}$ can be regarded as a totally ordered multiset with one element appearing twice and the another element appearing once.